# better way to design this exam db tables

Tags: database

I have a database consisting of userTable and subjectTable. The userTable should have exactly any 4 subjects from the list of subjects in the subjectTable and these for subjects are the subjects for the exams taken at a sitting...my table structure right now is:

```
UserTable
----------
id
fName
lName
.
.
.
subject1
subject2
subject3
subject4
```

```
subjectTable
----------
id
subjectName
```

```
examTable
----------
examID
subject1
subject2
subject3
subject4
date
score
```

Each exam subject has its own table in other to be able to record the individual scores, the four tables are the same format

```
examSubject1   examSubject2     examSubject3      examSubject4
------------   ------------     -------------     -------------
examID         examID           examID            examID
subject        subject          subject           subject
score          score            score             score
```

The userTable gets the subjects from the subjectTable, the examTable gets the subjects from the userTable and the examSubjects gets the subject and examID from the examTable...
Am looking for a way to link the relationship and also avoid the error of duplicate keys...How do i do it better?

Answer (score 0):

In your case i create this db

```
User
--------
userId
fName
lName

subjectTable
----------
subjectId
subjectName


examTable
----------
examId
subjectId
userId
date
score
```

with this db scheme you can get all info with join table.

Comment: Am not an expert with msql queries....how do i  implement join on these tables since the userTable must have exactly 4 subjects?

Comment: you can insert many subjectName with the same subjectId and in your query u use join query from this table.

Comment: The user table has to be updated each time the user edits the lists of subjects he is taking.... So, the user's subject list is only updated after it has been inserted ... The list is always four in number, and updated when the user changes the subjects...